# PostgreSQL query and convert a column with Ruby serialized YAML to JSON

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am connecting to a PostgreSQL database, which connected to an old Rails app. It has a table `versions`  and it has a column with Ruby serialized YAML. From Postico, I would like to do a SELECT query but convert a column with Ruby serialized YAML to JSON.

I tried looking around and found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/statique/4004202) but did not return as expected.

YAML column

```
--- !ruby/object:BillingInfo
gateway_identifier: blah 
organisation: blah
billing_email: blah
reference: blah
phone: blah
country: blah
vat: blah
subscription: blah
```

expected query result

```
{
  "--- !ruby/object":"BillingInfo",
  "gateway_identifier": "blah ",
  "organisation": "blah",
  "billing_email": "blah",
  "reference": "blah",
  "phone": "blah",
  "country": "blah",
  "vat": "blah",
  "subscription": "blah"
}
```

updates:
I tried the suggested from the comment by Gerard

```
SELECT jsonb_pretty(jsonb_build_object('YAML', data)) FROM versions;
```

but this returned

```
{
    "YAML": "--- !ruby/object:BillingInfo\ngateway_identifier: blah \norganisation: blah\nbilling_email: blah\nreference: blah\nphone: blah\ncountry: blah\nvat: blah\nsubscription: blah"
}
```